# Retrieving result of passed-in callback in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm attempting to write a small wrapper around `localStorage` similar to how Rails fetches a cached result.  In Rails the pattern is like this:

```
# Data.find is a block which just returns the data if the cache key was not found
data = Rails.cache.fetch(key, options) { Data.find }
```

In JavaScript I'm having a difficult time getting the result of the callback which is executed to return the data if the cache is empty.

```
function fetch(key, callback) {
    var result = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (result) {
        return JSON.parse(result);
    } else {
        result = callback();
        if (result) {
            result = JSON.stringify(result);
            localStorage.setItem(key, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
var data = fetch('projects-delivered', function() {
    var result;
    d3.json('/projects/delivered.json', function(data) {
        result = formatDates(data);
    });
    return result;
});
```

Data is always undefinded though.  Do I need to pass in another callback, or synchronize some how?  Or, is this not even possible with JavaScript's async nature?

Comment: Set up a demo of this on jsfiddle.net so that people can see it in action and help to debug it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your AJAX runs asynchronously, so your callback will always return `undefined`.

You'll have to call your callback from within the `getData` function:

```js
function fetch(key, getData, callback) {
    var result = localStorage.getItem(key);

    result ? callback(JSON.parse(result)) : getData(function (result) {
        result && localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(result));

        callback(result);
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```js
fetch('projects-delivered', function (callback) {
    d3.json('/projects/delivered.json', function (data) {
        callback(formatDates(data));
    });
}, function (data) {
    // Use the data
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can return a promise from your `fetch` function:

```js
function fetch(key, getData) {
    var result = localStorage.getItem(key);

    if (result) return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(result));

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        getData(function (result) {
            result && localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(result));

            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Then use the returned promise:

```js
var promise = fetch('projects-delivered', function (callback) {
    d3.json('/projects/delivered.json', function (data) {
        callback(formatDates(data));
    });
});

promise.then(function (data) {
    // Use the data
});
```